# Как написать модульные тесты для конструкторов класса java используя TestNG

Tags: java, конструктор, testng

Как написать модульные тесты для конструкторов класса java используя TestNG
например для таких конструкторов

```
public Man(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Man(String name, int years) {
    this(name);
    this.years = years;
}

public Man(String name, int years, String color) {
    this(name, years);
    this.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что именно вы хотите тестировать? Что при создании объекта его полям присваиваются значения параметров, переданных в конструктор? Если да, то это можно сделать так:

```
@Test
public void testConstructorWithName() {
    String name = "name";
    Man man = new Man(name);
    assertEquals(man.getName(), name);
}
```

Хотя обычно подобные тесты не пишут.
Вообще, тесты предназначены для тестирования какой-либо функциональности, а "правильный" конструктор не должен ее содержать. Конструктор должен  только инициализировать объект, а уже методы объекта - реализовать функционал, который необходимо тестировать.

**UPD** из комментариев - для проверки private-поля класса (но делать этого стоит):

```
@Test
public void testConstructorWithName() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    String name = "name";
    Man man = new Man(name);

    Field field = Man.class.getDeclaredField("name");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String val = (String) field.get(man);

    assertEquals(val, name);
}
```

Comment: А если гетера нет и переменные в классе приватные? 
Есть задание написать подобный тест)

Comment: Странное у вас задание... Обычно private-часть класса не тестируют (поля, методы), т.к. она может меняться - главное, чтобы public-интерфейс класса был прежним. Когда вы тестируете public-методы, в них автоматически проверяются приватные. Если вам все таки нужно проверить приватные поля, то можно использовать рефлексию - добавил в ответ.